# Continuous AEM login calls from GoogleHC/1.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, aem

We are upgrading to AEM 6.3 and have our instances hosted on Google Cloud GCP. On my AEM access.log, I am seeing continuous log of:

```
130.211.1.24 - anonymous 09/Mar/2018:11:40:05 -0500 "GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 11177 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.24 - anonymous 09/Mar/2018:11:40:05 -0500 "GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 11177 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.71 - anonymous 09/Mar/2018:11:40:06 -0500 "GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 11177 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.3.236 - anonymous 09/Mar/2018:11:40:06 -0500 "GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 11177 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.1.71 - anonymous 09/Mar/2018:11:40:07 -0500 "GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 11177 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
130.211.3.236 - anonymous 09/Mar/2018:11:40:07 -0500 "GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 11177 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
```

Some daemon process/script is trying to hit AEM instance continuously. This is happening for both author and publish. This is vanilla AEM instance and not inplace upgraded instance. And we dont have any monitor scripts or processes setup yet. Just standing an AEM instance and checking logs, we are noticing this issue.

How to solve this? Is this issue faced by someone else as well?

Comment: Nothing to worry. I would say it is the Google Cloud Health Check ( See the User Agent: GoogleHC). You can read more about that here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks).

Comment: I see so google is hitting my server. It just pollutes my log and annoying. How do I tell google not to health check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the health checks, you can delete them in GCP console, under Compute Engine > Health checks menu.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I have to live with this. Health Check is highly recommended and critical for application and my other monitors are impacted if I disabled. I didnt like the access.log files getting polluted.